# Excel - How to vlookup data from various columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now , in order to find the answer (I want to know if there is 1 and 4 in the data)

I need to manually combine the data from Column 1 and Column 2 and create a new Column

How to `vlookup()` the answer from various columns? not need to manually combine the data? There are hundreds of columns in the data, and each column contains thousands of data

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? You return result is same as your input result? Do you want to return column header?

Comment: I want to know if there is 1 and 4 in the data

Comment: Then try `=IF(COUNTIFS(C3:D5,A3)>0,"Yes","No")`.

Comment: So the expected result is a column of thousands of rows with `TRUE/FALSE` answers indicating whether a row (hundreds of columns) has both, `1` and `4`?

Answer (score 3):

As per comment, `COUNTIFS()` may work for you. Try-

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C3:D5,A3)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Match 2 Values

**Spilling**

```
=LET(Data,C2:M21,Value1,1,Value2,4,y,"Yes",n,"No",
    br,BYROW(Data,LAMBDA(r,
        ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Value1,r)*XMATCH(Value2,r)))),
IF(br,y,n))
```

[image]

**For a Single Row**

TRUE/FALSE

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,C2:M2,0)*(MATCH(4,C2:M2,0)))
```

Yes/No

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,C2:M2,0)*MATCH(4,C2:M2,0)),"Yes","No")
```

### EDIT: More Flexibility

- You can use `TOCOL` to write the values to the Value column (`v`) excluding empty cells and cells containing error values. Then you can compare the number of numeric matches per row (`COUNT()`) with the number of rows (`c`) of the Value column.
- Now the `Values` argument has become very flexible.

```
=LET(Data,C2:M21,Values,O2:P11,y,"Yes",n,"No",
    v,TOCOL(Values,3),c,ROWS(v),
    br,BYROW(Data,LAMBDA(r,
        COUNT(XMATCH(v,r))=c)),
IF(br,y,n))
```

[image]